# Creating a multithreading application in vc6 with boost library?

Tags: c++, visual-c++-6, boost-thread

Is it possible to create a multithreading application in VC6 with boost library?
If it is possible, what are some relevant tutorials.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, I have done this successfully, but with Boost v1.30.0. So if you have trouble with the latest versions of the Boost libraries, you might want to go back a year or five. I recall I started getting all sorts of internal compiler errors, *et al.*, when trying to upgrade Boost -- so I didn't, but rather went on using v1.30.0 until I was able to upgrade Visual C++ as well. Even the old versions of Boost are very stable and useful, they just have less features.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_37_0/doc/html/thread.html

Answer (score 0):

A quick google for "boost thread example" turns up lots of good hits.

Answer (score 0):

The Boost.Thread library provides thead creation and manipulation facilities. Read the boost documentation (link was provided in litb's answer). It also provides synchronization bojects (mutexs). Boost is cross platform and is compatible with VS6.

As for the rest of the boost libraries - they are usually thread safe, but read the documentation of each particular library of details.

Comment: <p>There seems to be some confusion regarding whether the recent releases of boost support vc6 or not, e.g.: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vcgeneral/thread/453ed2c8-c2c4-4497-9360-1978bdee0f7d</p>

<p>I guess this varies by library... Does anyone have a definitive answer?</p>

Comment: Ok so comments don't support HTML... Here's a working link (I hope): http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vcgeneral/thread/453ed2c8-c2c4-4497-9360-1978bdee0f7d